# Regex Lookahead (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a quick question about regex for PHP.

My code:

```
^(\d{0,4}?)\.(?=(\d{1,2}))$
```

doesn't seem to work, where it's supposed to capture an optional group of up to 4 digits, then look ahead and conditionally capture a period based on if it captures a group of 1-2 digits. 
Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the right way to do it - nothing about your regex indicates that the `.` is optional.

Try:

```
^(\d{0,4})(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?$
```

This will match up to four digits, which may optionally be followed by a dot, then one or two digits. In any case, the two subpatterns will contain the groups of digits.